# sanitizing phone number input woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to block some phone number on woocommerce checkout page

**if the phone numbers started with 0111 or 0222 or 0333 it should prompt an error message.**

---

By default WooCommerce checkout fields support the following attributes for the fields

```
$defaults = array(
'type'              => 'text',
'label'             => '',
'description'       => '',
'placeholder'       => '',
'maxlength'         => false,
'required'          => false,
'id'                => $key,
'class'             => array(),
'label_class'       => array(),
'input_class'       => array(),
'return'            => false,
'options'           => array(),
'custom_attributes' => array(),
'validate'          => array(),
'default'           => '',
);
```

for now i could only set "maxlength" numbers with below function

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields )
{        
  $fields['billing']['billing_phone']['maxlength'] = 10;      
  return $fields;    
}
```

Comment: This can be done in `woocommerce_checkout_process`action hook, where you will analyze the phone data with the value `$_POST['billing_phone']` Then you will return an message error, if the value start with 0111 or 0222 or 0333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try something like this :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'phoneValidate');

function phoneValidate() {
    $billing_phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'billing_phone');

    if ( /* you condition */) {
        wc_add_notice(__('Invalid Phone Number.'), 'error');
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. its done on billing phone with your help..  can you help me for use this function on custom field?   "get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'CustomField', true )"

Comment: you mean what exactly ? how you added your custom field ?

Comment: thank you.  its done on that custom field now.  i handle that.